# OpenGL get FBO overall color fast

Tags: opengl

I am making a simple lightmap creation program. I do this with hemicube rendered at every lightmap texel and corrected with spetial texture. Then i am storing an overall color for each hemicube face like this:

```
glHint(GL_GENERATE_MIPMAP_HINT, GL_NICEST);
glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

GLfloat cur_pixel[3];
glGetTexImage(GL_TEXTURE_2D, top_mip_level, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, cur_pixel);
final_pixels[index * 3] += cur_pixel[0];
final_pixels[index * 3 + 1] += cur_pixel[1];
final_pixels[index * 3 + 2] += cur_pixel[2];
```

So i am generating mipmap and getting top mip-level pixel. 
glGenerateMipmap seams to be quiet slow to be called 5 times for every lightmap pixel. Is there a faster way getting overal fbo texture color?
  I tried to use stereographic projection instead of hemicube, it was faster but i got terrible artifacts even with tesselating in geometry shader.

Comment: Wait, what? `glGenerateMipmap (...)` takes the texture and generates ***ALL*** of the lower LODs for the entire base image in a single call. If you are calling it 5 times without making any changes to the top-level texture image in-between this is absolutely unnecessary.

Comment: Thats why i am asking for a better solution. I thought calculate a sum on CPU is slower than generate mipmaps.

Comment: Just realized i read your comment inatentively. I calling generatemipmap once per cubeface. I know it generates all levels ofcourse. So for 5 faces i have 5 calls per lightmap pixel.

Comment: I am using 1 fbo with just 2d texture, for each face i clear it, render scene, store overall color (+=), repeat.

Comment: Have you considered using a cube map or (on newer hardware) a 5 layer 2D array texture for this? You can generate the mipmaps for all cube faces and texture array layers in a single call, which *may* improve performance. Cube maps are basically 6 layer 2D textures that are supported even on hardware that does not support arbitrary texture arrays.

Comment: Nevermind, I just realized you are discussing hemicubes - the other 4 faces are half-resolution, so this would not work :-\